# UITableViewCell reused prematurely

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a conditional breakpoint when the `indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 3`. The first time the breakpoint is triggered, and I run

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

The cell is the same cell as the cell at `indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0`, rather than `nil`, which is what I would expect. I made sure the number of rows for section 3 is 4. Why isn't the cell `nil`?

Comment: If might be the same cell if indexPath.section = 0 & row = 0 is scrolled off the screen.  UITableView is pretty good about recycling cells.

Comment: It's not premature, the table view will recycle the cells when appropriate. Anyway, why do you care? Are you asking a theoretical question here, or do you have a specific problem with the cells being recycled?

Comment: I run initialization code when the cell is `nil`. I have 12 other rows that return `nil` the first time `dequeue' is called for their 'indexPath'.

Answer (score 0):

**I just give you suggestion**, if you want to give restriction to reusability of cell then follow my below answer , But i would like to **MENTION** here that it is bad for memory management.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         /// Put your code here.
     }

      /// Put your code here.

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView does not necessarily start drawing with the first row. It could start drawing anywhere depending on which part of the view needs to be drawn at a given time.

The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method is only ever going to return `nil` once. After that it will forever return a cell that was previously used for some other row.

If you have two rows with incompatible cells, then you need to have a different identifier for each. Perhaps you should have an identifier for each section in your case for example.

The point is if you're drawing a thousand table view rows that look almost identical, except maybe the text is different, then you can create a single cell and then change the text but leave everything else (fonts, accessory view, etc) exactly the same as it goes through and draws each one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`, use

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
```

...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with no checks for a `nil` cell.

Comment: If you're using Storyboards, you don't need to do this.